# Records for Sales Person

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

I am designing this database and c# app, that a record gets saved to database. now say we have three Sales Person and each should be assigned a record in strict rotation so they get to work on equal amount of records.

What I have done so far was to create one table called `Records` and one `SalesPerson`, the Records would have salesperson `id` as foreign key and another column that would say which agent it is assigned to and will increment this column.

Do you think this is a good design, if not can you give any ideas?

Comment: what's a record, a sales opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite confusing as I suspect you're using the database term 'record' aswell as an object/entity 'Record'.

The simple concept of having a unique identifier in one table that also features as a foreign key in another table is fine though, yes. It avoids redundancy.

[Basics of normalisation](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: say if i have a table called "Records" and table called "SalesPerson". and SalesPerson ID is foreign key in Records table. now how do I assign equal number of record for each sales person?

Comment: @Sam1: What do you mean "assign"? Do you want distribute available records between available persons at some moment?

Comment: You need an n-m table. So you have a table with SalesPersonID and RecordID. Here you can "assign" your record to different SalesPerson. Does it sound good? I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: The motion of 'assigning' that you've mentioned and the fact your post is tagged with C# leads me to believe that you are writing a program that makes this assignment. The logic of when and who to assign a Record to must be done at a business layer - not the data level. i.e. The decision of whether all SalesPerson's have an equal amount of records or not must be done in code, there are no "OOTB" SQL constraints to dictate this. You could write a procedure/trigger at the very least but this has nothing to do with how you've normalised the tables.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would use the analytical functions `ROW_NUMBER` and `NTILE` (assuming your RDBMS supports them). This way you can allocate each available sales person a pseudo id incrementing upwards from 1, then randomly allocate each unassigned record one of these pseudo ids to assign them equally between sales people. Using pseudo ids rather than actual ids allows for the `SalesPersonID` field not being continuous. e.g.

```
-- CREATE SOME SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @SalesPerson TABLE (SalesPersonID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Active BIT NOT NULL)
DECLARE @Record TABLE (RecordID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SalesPersonFK INT NULL, SomeOtherInfo VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @SalesPerson VALUES ('TEST1', 1), ('TEST2', 0), ('TEST3', 1), ('TEST4', 1);
INSERT @Record (SomeOtherInfo)
SELECT  Name
FROM    Sys.all_Objects
```

With this sample data the first step is to find the number of available sales people to allocate records to:

```
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @SalesPerson WHERE Active = 1)
```

Next using CTEs to contain the window functions (as they can't be used in join clauses)

```
;WITH Records AS
(   SELECT  *,
            NTILE(@Count) OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) [PseudoSalesPersonID]
    FROM    @Record
    WHERE   SalesPersonFK IS NULL       -- UNALLOCATED RECORDS
), SalesPeople AS
(   SELECT  SalesPersonID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesPersonID) [RowNumber]
    FROM    @SalesPerson
    WHERE   Active = 1                  -- ACTIVE SALES PEOPLE
)
```

Finally update the records CTE with the actual sales personID rather than a pseudo id

```
UPDATE  Records
SET     SalesPersonFK = SalesPeople.SalesPersonID
FROM    Records
        INNER JOIN SalesPeople
            ON PseudoSalesPersonID = RowNumber
```

**[ALL COMBINED IN AN SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a19335/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Its mostly as DeeMac said. But if your `Record` is an object (i.e. it has all the work details or its a sale or a transaction) then you need to separate that table. Have a table `Record` with all the details to that particular object. Have another table `Salesman' with all the details about the Sales Person. (In a good design, you would only add particular business related attributes of the position in this table. All the personal detail will go in a different table)

Now for your problem, you can build two separate tables. One would be `Record_Assignment` where you will assign a `Record` to a `Salesman`. This table will hold all the active jobs. Another table will be `Archived_Record_Assignment` which will hold all the past jobs. You move all the completed jobs here.

For equal assignment of work, you said you want circular assignment. I am not sure if you want to spread work amongst all sales person available or only certain number. Usually assignments are given by team. Create a table (say table `SalesTeam`)with the Salesman ids of the sales persons you want to assign the jobs (add team id, if you have multiple teams working on their own assigned work areas or customers. That's usually the case). When you want to assign new job, query the `Record_Assignment` table for last record, get the Salesman id and assign the job to the next salesman in the `SalesTeam` table. The assignment will be done through business logic (coding).

I am not fully aware of your scenario. These are all my speculations so if you see something off according to your scenario, let me know.

Good Luck!